# PrimeNG TreeTable cannot get Row index

Tags: angular, primeng

Trying to use `rowIndex` inside `TreeTable`.
With `DataTable` `rowIndex` works fine, but with `TreeTable` `rowIndex` is undefined.

```
<p-treeTable [value]="files1">
  <p-header>Basic</p-header>
  <p-column header="ID">
    <ng-template let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
      <p class="rw-center-align">{{rowIndexValue}}</p>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
  <p-column field="size" header="Size"></p-column>
  <p-column field="type" header="Type"></p-column>
  <p-column header="Actions">
    <ng-template let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
      <button pButton label="Add child" (click)="addChild(rowIndex)"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-treeTable>
```

Here in `addChild()` method I'm getting `rowIndexValue` as `undefined`, and `ID` column is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc :

rowIndex well exists for [DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) but not for [TreeTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable)